# Logical Reasoning: Identify next figure

Tags: induction, pattern-recognition

I came across this logical reasoning/ abstract reasoning question in my logical reasoning book. Can somebody please help me identify the next pattern:
[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Let's see what it is not. It is not the number of closed shapes (4,4,1,2,3), it's not vertices with more than two edges (1,8,0,2,4), it doesn't have anything to do with concavity or shape of exterior edges. Number of exterior edges is (12,6,4,2,3) which is nice for the most part but broken for the last one. The first 3 have some sort of square element but the second two don't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of regions in the pictures (ignoring the background):

$4, 5, 1, 2, 3$.

So probably it will loop back to $4$ in the next picture, hence **B**.

(Editorial: Not a particularly good puzzle in my opinion.)

Answer (score 0):

This isn't great, but it's the best I could come up with.

> **E**

There is a pattern to the number of lines making each pair of shapes, and it goes

> (12,10) ,  (4,2), (6,**4**)

**E** having 4 lines.

Answer (score 0):

Answer is B according to me. Check the number of divisions of the figures. They appear to be a,a+1,b,b+1,c,c+1. 4 in first, 5 in second, 1 in third, 2 in fourth and so on.